# How to store varbinary in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, types, varbinary

Just a quick question..

Out of two options mentioned below, how to store to `varbinary` column in MySQL?

```
public_key = '67498930589635764678356756719'
```

or

```
public_key = 67498930589635764678356756719
```

Will the second method work? I am into an emergency moment working on a production server and didn't want to experiment on it.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Printable data can be inserted using quotes. Non-printable data can be inserted using hexadecimal values. I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO Table(VarBinaryColumn) VALUES('Printable data') -- Will be stored as binary representation using the charset of the operating system

INSERT INTO Table(VarBinaryColumn) VALUES(0x12345) -- Non-printable binary data
```